# Kellerman .Net Object Comparison - Ignore DataTable column names and data types

Tags: c#, object, compare

I'm using Kellerman .Net Object Comparison to compare C# DataTables.  It's mostly working well for me.

However, I'm stumped at how to ignore:

- DataTable column names
- DataTable column data types.

In most of the DataTable comparisons I need to run, data types can be different, but the content is the same following a cast or convert.  Typically I get an incoming string on the left hand side which is an integer on the right hand side.

Also, I typically get different column names.

I've attempted something like:

```
config.AttributesToIgnore.Add( dt.Columns[0].ColumnName ) ;

config.AttributesToIgnore.Add( typeof(dt.Columns[0].DataType) );
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, I'm stuck with pinpointing the exact type I want to ignore and the expected datatype required to add the element.

IgnoreObjectTypes is useless to me, because that only checks whether both sides are DataTables not the column datatype within the DataTable itself.

The best way to describe my problem is by looking at the table below

```html
<style>
.nomatch{
background-color: #ff9999;
}
.match{
background-color: #99ff99;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr><td class="nomatch">System.Int32</td><td class="match">System.String</td><td class="match">System.Int32</td><td style="border-left: 2px dotted blue; " class="nomatch">System.String</td><td class="match">System.String</td><td class="match">System.Int32</td></tr>
<tr><td class="match">Year</td><td class="match">Region</td><td class="nomatch">Count</td><td style="border-left: 2px dotted blue; " class="match">Year</td><td class="match">Region</td><td class="nomatch">Column1</td></tr>
</table>
```

The elements I've highlighted in red are flagged as differences by Compare .Net Objects, however I want to ignore them and just concentrate on the data itself.

Comment: which Comparer do you use ?

Comment: The default comparer, something like `result = compareLogic.Compare(dtLeft, dtRight);`

Comment: try this one , `new DataRowComparer(RootComparerFactory.GetRootComparer())`, compare two rows

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, because it requires that I manage the looping over each row.  I'll give it a go and see what the performance is like.